# flutter localization without MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, internationalization, flutter-layout

I am using `flutter_localizations` plugin. The root view is a `MaterialApp` widget and I can easily call `AppLocalizations.of(context).text_id` to get the localized string. The problem is I have some child views that my app navigates to that are not based on `MaterialApp` and calling `AppLocalizations.of(context).text_id` there does not work. Is there a way to still use localization in views that do not have `MaterialApp` as parent?

Comment: Is there are any update??